# After ajax form submission, the page reloads when it's not supposed to

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want voting form (in index.php) to submit without the page reload and get results from external page in index.php

HTML

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
</head>
<div class="polling" id="polling_id">
    <br><br>    

    <form id="poll_form" method="POST" action="process-vote.php" />
    <div class="poll_objects">
        <input type="hidden" name="o1" value="<?php echo $option1; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="o2" value="<?php echo $option2; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="o3" value="<?php echo $option3; ?>" />
        <span class="footer_font"><input type="radio" name="radio_1" value="<?php echo $option1;?>" id="radio" /><label for="radio"><?php echo $option1;?></label> </span><br><br>
        <span class="footer_font"><input type="radio" name="radio_1" value="<?php echo $option2;?>" id="radio2" /><label for="radio2"><?php echo $option2;?></label></span><br><br>
        <span class="footer_font"><input type="radio" name="radio_1" value="<?php echo $option3;?>" id="radio3" /><label for="radio3"><?php echo $option3;?></label></span><br><br>
        <div class="float_buttons">
            <input type="submit" name="submit_vote" value="Vote!" class="button" />
            <input type="submit" name="results" value="Poll Results" class="button"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Ajax

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {     
        $.ajax({    
            $('#poll_form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // note where the e comes from.
                var a = $(this).serialize();
                $("#polling_id").load("poll-results.php");
            });
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Looking at this coding, for me it seems everything is correct. However the page opens the action page of the form. Please provide help.

Comment: invalid code so will throw errors... `ajax ` shoudl be within submit handler. Also not attempting to send any data

Comment: @charlietfl true :D, the submit work don't even know why or how.

Comment: Considering all of the answers i came up with this.  

$(document).ready(function() { 

   $('#poll_form').submit(function(e) {

  $.ajax({
  url: "process-vote.php",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( html ) {
   $("#polling_id").load("poll_results.php"); 
  });

    });

});  And it still doesnt work

Comment: off course, on form submit you send the form to the server, no ajax here!! ajax hold for async javascript and xml, form submit is synchronous, which means you send the entire form to the server, what the purpose of ajax if you are doing that?

Comment: @user3186034 look at my answer and try to do a jquery.load. on your jquery $(document).ready extract the parameter from the form and send them along with the jquery.load call.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code does not compile, because you are not doing an ajax call, you are passing a form submit to an object literal which will cause an error after the execution of form submit, that why your form is reloading.

```
<script> 
   $(document).ready(function() { 
      $.ajax({  //this is object literal notation and you are returning a function value to it... doesn't make any sense.

          $('#poll_form').submit(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             // note where the e comes from.
             var a = $(this).serialize();
             $("#polling_id").load("poll-results.php");
          });

      });
   });
</script>
```

Also an ajax call should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#results" ).append( html );
  });
```

See this link it's all [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Also if you are trying to perform a load of data based on the jquery.load you shouldn't perform a submit, but you can send data within your load request:

```
$( "#feeds" ).load( "feeds.php", { limit: 25 }, function() {
  alert( "The last 25 entries in the feed have been loaded" );
});
```

Here you are passing parameter limit, but you can be passing name, address, age, etc.

See load documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/), there is no need for you to perform a submit.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `ajax` call and try if it works

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#poll_form').submit(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           // note where the e comes from.
           var a = $(this).serialize();
           $("#polling_id").load("poll-results.php");
     });
}
```

Comment: Copied my answer? next time try coming up with your own answer.

Comment: I copied the question,  not your answer. Please check the first version of the question...

Comment: The comment equals my answer.

Comment: edit the question and i'll upvote it, it won't let me.